# Conver grViz & htmlwidget to ggplot object in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert a grViz object to a ggplot2 object in R? when i try to combine grViz and other plot using patchwork, there will be an error.

here is my code:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(patchwork)

"digraph G {
A -> B
}" %>% grViz -> plt.grviz

class(plt.grviz)
# [1] "grViz"      "htmlwidget"

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_point() -> plt.mcars

# error
# plt.mcars + plt.grviz
```

i tried conver it to svg, then load in, but still have some error